# NSDictionaryResultType does not fetch objects in relationship - Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I set the `NSFetchRequest` result type to `NSDictionaryResultType` when fetching objects from core data. When set `NSDictionaryResultType`, relationship objects not in the result dictionary. What may be the issue in this code. If `NSDictionaryResultType` not going to work, how would I fetch the relationship objects?

```
// get manageObjectContext
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeName"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"anEntity", nil];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", @"anId", anArray];

NSError *error;
NSArray *existingTopics = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
fetchRequest = nil;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `propertiesToFetch`.  See the class reference for `NSFetchRequest`, currently found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/propertiesToFetch).

**Note**: this property does not work for one-to-many (or many-to-many) relationships.

For such relationships, the related objects will have to be added manually.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
NSMutableArray *mutableResults = [results mutableCopy];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < mutableResults.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *result = mutableResults[i];

    // Do a similar fetch for the related objects, returning dictionary
    // representations.  Repeat as necessary for each 1toMany relationship.
    NSArray *objectsFor1toManyRelationship = [self fetchRelationShipFor:result[@"identifier"]];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableResult = [result mutableCopy];
    mutableResult[@"1toManyRelationship"] = objectsFor1toManyRelationship;
    mutableResults[i] = [mutableResult copy];
}
```

Comment: Yes.  That would appear to not be possible.  I guess you will need to manage that yourself.

Comment: By the way, why do you want a dictionary representation anyway, given the limitations?